# Nested Xml Nodelists in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to isolate the `<string>` elements in each `<question>` element in the XML below. 
I used Xpath which is what I'm most familiar with. Basically, I use a `SelectNodes("question")` and if pointed at the XML below it will return the correct 5 elements. Then I want to iterate on the `<string>` elements inside each `<question>`. 
I don't want to go directly to "question/string" as it will return all `<string>` instances in the XML file. I have some work to do within a certain question that's not included here, the actual file is a lot more complex than this but this is what I'm struggling with.

Here's the code I used. It returns all `<string>` elements for the file and not just the node I'm working with at any given moment.

```
XmlNodeList questions = doc.SelectNodes("//question");
string question = null;
foreach (XmlElement qquestion in questions) //I also tried XmlNode here
{
  XmlNodeList qstrings = qquestion.SelectNodes("//string");
  foreach (XmlNode qstring in qstrings)
  {
    question = qstring.InnerText; //There's a lot more processing I'll do here
  }
 }
```

And here's my simplified XML. Thanks for any pointers.

```
<content version="1.0">
    <question>
      <string>Question 1 part 1</string>
      <string>Question 1 part 2</string>
      <graphic scale=".8" align="center" yOffset="-50" xOffset="50" asset="Numline_Triangle"/>
      <graphic scale="1.2" align="center" yOffset="20" asset="Numline_Shapes_0_40"/>
    </question>
    <question>
      <string>Question 2</string>
      <graphic scale=".8" align="center" yOffset="-50" xOffset="50" asset="Numline_Square"/>
      <graphic scale="1.2" align="center" yOffset="20" asset="Numline_Shapes_0_40"/>
    </question>
    <question>
      <string>Question 3 part 1</string>
      <string>Question 3 part 2</string>
      <graphic scale=".8" align="center" yOffset="-50" xOffset="50" asset="Numline_Square"/>
      <graphic scale="1.2" align="center" yOffset="20" asset="Numline_Shapes_60_100"/>
    </question>
    <question>
      <string>Question 4</string>
      <graphic scale=".8" align="center" yOffset="-50" xOffset="50" asset="Numline_Circle"/>
      <graphic scale="1.2" align="center" yOffset="20" asset="Numline_Shapes_60_100"/>
    </question>
    <question>
      <string>Question 5</string>
      <graphic scale=".8" align="center" yOffset="-50" xOffset="50" asset="Numline_Triangle"/>
      <graphic scale="1.2" align="center" yOffset="20" asset="Numline_Shapes_60_100"/>
    </question>
  </content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It returns all `<string>` elements for the file and not just the node I'm working with at any given moment.

Yes. That's the correct behaviour, because `//string` returns all **globally** present `string` elements.

To return only all of the *descendant* `string` elements, just add a `.` at the beginning of your XPath-1.0  expression like this:

```
...
XmlNodeList qstrings = qquestion.SelectNodes(".//string");
foreach (XmlNode qstring in qstrings)
{
  question = qstring.InnerText; //There's a lot more processing I'll do here
}
...
```

The expression `.//string` returns all of the `string` elements that are descendants of the current `qquestion` XmlNode.

Comment: Fantastic, I knew it was simple but couldn't figure it out. Thank you.